# Iframe - Selenium + Nodejs

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

If the HTML code looks like this

````html
<div class="something">
  <div>
   <iframe src="something">
``` how would I be able to switch the iframe to that above using selenium in nodejs
````

Comment: how many entry do you see for `//iframe` tag in HTMLDOM ?

Comment: based from the inspect element, there's only 1

Comment: Can you share the HTML in the text format for the iframe. steps to copy: `Press F12 in Chrome -> go to element section -> then right click on the element you want to share the outer HTML - > select copy and then outer HTML`

Comment: I'll send it as a screenshot form instead. https://prnt.sc/q-gvHhrWsY8S

Comment: from screenshot it is too difficult to write a locator at answerer end.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/qMWuAfKW

Comment: thnx, there's no captcha right on the page ?

Comment: There is hCaptcha, and I want to switch to the captcha's iframe and click the checkbox on it, but I get stuck on switching to iframe

Comment: the site link is discord.com/register

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To switch to the  [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) you can use the following lines of code:

```
// Store the web element
const iframe = driver.findElement(By.css('div.something > div > iframe[src="something"]'));

// Switch to the frame
await driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
```

Comment: https://prnt.sc/KCG2IFmDMMca - I tried on doing `let button = tab.findElement(swd.By.css("div.class here > div > iframe[src='link']"));` but it says it cant find element